# Slow screen sharing with zoom, google meet, etc

Tags: display, screen, sharing

**"Screen sharing"** with *zoom meetings*, or *google meet* (on chrome or firefox) it is seriously **slow**. Both on wayland, and xorg. Using the open source nouveau drivers, or the proprietary nvidia drivers.

This laptop it is used as a desktop, without a battery, and connected via ethernet. The connection is fast and as stable as it can be. The same can be said about the video call itself; zero issues of any kind. The problems, the lag, is only when I share my screen with the participants of a meeting/video call.

At this point, I don't know if this has anything to do with wayland, xorg, hardware acceleration, gpu, drivers, or Linux as a whole. But I would like to make this work.

I am open to suggestions. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you connected via Wifi? Is your MTU 1500, when it should be 1492? The terminal command `ip link` will tell. Should be fixed on your DHCP server, or, temporarily, by `sudo ip link set dev _yourdevicename_ mtu 1492`

Comment: Ethernet. The MTU seems to be on the default 1500. Thanks

Comment: You can use `ntop` to see which processes are using network bandwidth. Read `man ntop`. You may have to `sudo apt install ntop` first. MTU 1500 for Ethernet is OK.

Comment: @waltinator Thanks. Perhaps I did something wrong, but I did install ntopng with synaptic, then launch the command on the terminal, without success; there is a screenshot with the result.